# Does spring boot application support OpenJDK

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, spring-security

Can spring boot applications be made with openJDK instead of Oracle jdk? Are there any limitations?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, no problem reported so far.

I'm using **openJDK 1.8.0.xx** and **spring boot 1.5.9**

Comment: Thanks ! Are you using spring boot for a product that is being used in production? We keep Java always updated to its latest patch version in our product in every release. After upgrading the java version in your spring boot application, have you ever experienced spring related problems coming in

Comment: Yes also in production. And again no problem so far