# How is springboot able to run on OpenJDK considering that OpenJDK only implements JavaSE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am planning to switch to OpenJDK to write my spring boot project but for a while, I have stalled because I read that OpenJDK only implements JavaSE and not EE. My view Changed after I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49448866/does-spring-boot-application-support-openjdk) . 
My question is how would spring boot work with OpenJDK when OpenJDK only implements JavaSE and not Java EE and Springboot is a web framework?

Comment: All of Java EE runs on Java SE. Not just Spring Boot. Spring Boot uses an embedded Tomcat, Jetty or Undertow server, which itself comes with servlet support. All these are just Java libraries.

Comment: You'll no issues whatsoever. The only thing that you may notice are some packages missing due to them being proprietary Oracle code. We've been running Spring application on AdoptOpenJDK jres for some time now with no issues whatsoever.